# application requires a non-existing dll. (tinyxml2ddll was not found)

Tags: debugging, cmake, dll, hyperlink, dependencies

I have an application compiled by CMake. I compile it with Debug configuration. The application uses tinyxml2 library.
When I try to launch the application, it reports tinyxml2d.dll was not found, but I used tinyxml2.dll (without d suffix).
The dependency shown by dumpbin is as follows:

> File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
>
> Image has the following dependencies:
>
> ```
> fastrtpsd-2.8.dll
> fastcdrd-1.0.dll
> boost_locale-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.dll
> boost_log_setup-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.dll
> boost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.dll
> boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.dll
> boost_thread-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_77.dll
> tinyxml2.dll
> ```

The error is as below:

> The code execution cannot proceed because tinyxml2d.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

tinyxml2d is not defined anywhere in `CMakeLists.txt`. Variable `CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX` is not defined.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect error message and other relevant information to be included into the **question post** as **text**, not linked as image. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.